# What is the difference between CamlQuery and SPQuery

Tags: web-part, web-services, client-object-model, caml-query, spquery

Maybe a simple question, when to use **CamlQuery** and when to use **SPQuery** ?

I think that SPQuery is used inside a WebPart running on the SharePoint server, and that CamlQuery is part of the *Client Object Model* which is used when you connect from a client (CLI, Asp.Net or custom Web Service) to a SharePoint site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's right. [CamlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.aspx) is a class in the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` which is part of the Client Object Model which can be used through a .NET, Silverlight or JavaScript Application.

While [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery) is part of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll` which can be used on the Server Side in Farm or Sandbox solutions through Custom C#/.NET code.

Answer (score 1):

You're right [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) is part of the Server Side API and [CamlQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.aspx) is part of the Client Object Model.

So if your code is running on a server in the SharePoint Farm you can use SPQuery.

If your code isn't running on one of the servers, then you can use CamlQuery.

Answer (score 0):

While using CAMLQuery in COB ->  make sure you enclose your query with   and ofcourse the closure tag - as this is not SPQuery.Query

In CAMLQuery its ViewXML -> not  a Query !

my 1 cent !